# Replace value in stylesheet

Tags: css, react-native, replace

I am trying to replace value in stylesheet from function in react native.

I have *Styles.js* file with created stylesheet (when I have styles for my application) and I want to change one of values in this stylesheet from *screen function*.

```
export default StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'black',

    }
})
```

Now, the background color is black. I want to change color from **black** to **red**. I mean something like that:

```
export function DisplayScreen(props) {

   . . .

   return (
       <Pressable onPress={() => styles.screen.backgroundColor.replace('red')} >
            <Text>CHANGE COLOR</Text>
       </Pressable>

}
```

Of course **.replace** does not exist. Is there any approach on how I can change this?

Comment: If you have access to the DOM, why not just change the element directly?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Something to the effect of `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";`

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a `state` called `screenBackgroundColor` and change it from black to red when the button is pressed.

For example:

```
export function DisplayScreen(props) {
    const [screenBackgroundColor, setScreenBackgroundColor] = useState('black');
    . . .

    return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: screenBackgroundColor}}>
            <Pressable onPress={() => setButtonBackgroundColor('red')}>
                <Text>CHANGE COLOR</Text>
            </Pressable>
        </View>
    )
}
```